# Is there any way to get rid of bamboo?

Tags: weed-control

Is there any real way to get rid of bamboo?  I have tried digging, every variety of round up, even salting the ground but it just keeps growing.   Is there anything I can do (short of calling in an air strike)?

Comment: fire? always fire.

Comment: Burn the witch! Hm, maybe cover the ground with something non-transparent? Unfortunately I have tried this (against other weeds) and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [completebamboo.com](http://www.completebamboo.com/bamboo_removal.html), it depends somewhat on if you have running or clumping bamboo.

Basically you want to dig up as much of the root system as you can, and destroy any shoots that are above ground. But like you said, it's going to keep coming back. You just have to keep killing the new shoots until the root system runs out of energy and dies. Sounds like it may take several years.

If you don't want to kill it all but want to contain it, there are some special bamboo rhizome barriers that you can buy.

This is speculation of my part, but since bamboo likes slightly acidic soil with good drainage, maybe you could over-lime the soil to a ph it doesn't like, or overwater it until the rhizome rots.